# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when i config my subdomains

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, multisite

I use multisite in wordpress like this

```
144.1.1.3
144.1.1.3/another_site
```

I need to use two subdomains like this

```
mysubdomain.mysite.com.br for 144.1.1.3
```

and

```
mysubdomain2.mysite.com.br for 144.1.1.3/another_site
```

I changed wp_options for these subdomains and when i try to access has the message:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
```

I need to do some configuration?

Comment: You need to make DNS changes from your registrar. You have the same domain pointing to the same A record. You will probably need to use a CNAME to configure what you have described. Can you clarify why you're using `wp-options` to manage DNS? Also, you're using a subdomain with a subdirectory. Just point the root domain and the subdirectory to the same A record.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Read this: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/